# Microsoft Access 2016 loop query?

Tags: sql, vba, loops

I have a table that has account numbers and UPC numbers.  UPC number are unique, but each UPC may have several account numbers associated with it.  It may have only one account number, or it may have several account numbers.

What I would like to do is get a full list of the account numbers associated with the UPC field, but put them all in one result field, separated by either a comma or semicolon.

For example on the query result....

```
UPC                        Account Number
1225486214781              R0002458; R3325482; M2154865; M5214861; C2145789
```

Would a loop query enable me to do this?  If so, how would I go about putting it together?

Answer (score 0):

Consider Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated()](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) where you implement by doing the following:

1. Place the VBA public function code in a standard module (not behind any form/report).
2. Call it via an SQL  query. Below assumes UPC is a string column, otherwise remove single quote wrapping. Additionally, be sure to change default separator to semicolon.

   ```sql
   SELECT UPC,  
          ConcatRelated("[Account Number]", "myTable", "UPC = '" & [UPC] & "'",
                        strSeparator = "; ")
   FROM myTable;
   ```

Do note: since you are running a VBA-specific method, this function will not be available if you run MS Access outside the GUI (i.e., MSAccess.exe) such as ODBC/OLEDB connections.

Comment: Thanks.  I have been looking at Allen Browne's ConcantRelated(), but have not been able to creat the module without getting a compile error.  Here is what I am putting in:  SELECT PARCELNUMBER,  ConcatRelated("ACCOUNTNUMBER", "dbo_ACCOUNT", "PARCELNUMBER = " & [PARCELNUMBER])
FROM dbo_ACCOUNT;  

The table I am pulling from is dbo_ACCOUNT.

Comment: PARCELNUMBER replaces UPC in the above.

Comment: What error? Is *PARCELNUMBER* a string or number? See my note on this item.

Comment: PARCELNUMBER is AlphaNumeric set to 64 characters.

I have been working on this and got the module to save OK.  I realized that I had to put a WHERE statement in there to filter for records that were active and for the current tax year.  I was having issues with getting the where statement to work, so I did a make table, filtered for the accounts I wanted and am trying to run the concantrelated query from that table.  I am now getting an error saying:  Error 3075: Syntax error in string in query expression 'PARCELNUMBER= 2057170475174"

Comment: This means *PARCELNUMBER* is a string, so follow exactly as I had posted using *UPC* with single quote wrapping and not how you do with above comment which assumes a number. Do note: `ConcatRelated()` has an optional *strwhere* argument.

Comment: I didn't realize I omitted a single quote.   I am now getting past the point where it asks for the separator, however I am getting a different error.  Error 3070: The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize '-1' as a valid field name or expression.

I will look into using the strwhere argument once I can get everything else to work.

I appreciate all your help in this.  VBA is not one of my strong points.

Comment: OK, I got it working.  I had to remove the strSeparator = "; "   For some reason Microsoft access 2016 didn't like it.  It is giving me the results I was hoping for with a comma separator.  Thanks again!

Comment: Try passing empty values for *strWhere* and *strOrder* that you do not use (see empty commas): `ConcatRelated("[Account Number]", "myTable", "PARCELNUMBER = '" & [PARCELNUMBER] & "'", , , strSeparator = "; ")`